# CSS3 Pie not working at All, tried everything

Tags: css, css3pie

I'm trying to apply [css3pie](http://www.css3pie.com)

to my website,
and it dosen't seem to be applied at all.
I have tried anything i could find:

- Checked the path to PIE.htc, put it in main folder and used url(/PIE.htc), even tried full URL, nothing worked.
- Tried using PIE.php, that didn't work either.
- Tried adding "AddType text/x-component .htc" to the .htaccess file, no good
- Tried adding `position:relative;
  z-index: 0;`, No good.

The code i'm trying to apply is :

```
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
```

What am i missing?

**EDIT:**
if this matters, when i view the loaded css in IE, i see the behavior command is in same line like the next one, though syntax is correct

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem and nothing suggested here has fixed what's going on.

Comment: I know this is late.
Had same issue but with rounded corner...couldn't get it to work. Found out it's because I was using the 2.0 beta version. Gotta stick with rock solid 1.0 i guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Web Developer tools (F12) to see if there are any `<css3-container>` elements being created. If there aren't then there is a problem with your `behaviour` css declaration. If those elements exist, then don't change anything with your PIE.htc -- its a styling issue and you can mess around with things like `position:relative; z-index: 0;`.

Comment: So, you're not getting any `<css3-container>` elements? Is it the `box-shadow` in particular that's broken, or have you tried on other elements?

Comment: It's got to be something to do with the path. Can you check if you are getting any errors? Can you share a public link for the website?

Comment: I played around with (not sure what i did) and i do see <css3-container> but still dosen't work.

Comment: Sorry, without some more code, it is hard for me to tell what is wrong. See if you can create a minimal test case using http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 9):

Use your website link. Eg:

```
behavior: url('http://www.yoursite.com/css/PIE.php')
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

CSS3PIE places its generated  elements as a sibling of the element you are styling, with a z-index value of -1.
You may not see the result because it's behind some other element in the document. Try wrapping the elements you are styling inside a positionned container with an independent z-index.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Like this person says, try giving the element position:relative and perhaps also a z-index. This has solved my problems a couple of times.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your Server settings:

Assuming DIR "pie" is relative to your "root" DIR, try one of the following:

```
    behavior: url(/pie/PIE.php);
    behavior: url(pie/PIE.php);
```

Also try:

```
    position:relative; 
    z-index: 0;
```

Don't use IE filter hacks with PIE, example:

```
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0074a8',endColorstr='#006496',GradientType=0);
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJod…EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
```

Answer (score 1):

CSSPie3 does not support box-shadow when you are trying to use a blur. It's just not possible.

Instead, remove the blur, and your box-shadow shim will work.

See here for sources:

http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=991

http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

> Unfortunately PIE only supports rgba opacity in box-shadow if it has
>   no blur.
>
> http://css3pie.com/documentation/suppor ... ures/#rgba
>
> It's often possible to work around this by simply using a lighter
>   shade of your opaque color. If you want to let other browsers use the
>   rgba, you can use -pie-box-shadow to override it only for PIE.

Comment: Good information thank you. but i changed it and still no results as if it dosen't work AT all. i'm currently trying with absolute path http and with the PIE.php and same results

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hex-value notation for the color instead. In the documentation it says there are limitations to using rgba notation:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px #000;
filter: Alpha(Opacity=90);
opacity: 0.9;
behavior: url(/Pie.htc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. PIE didn't work at all, whether htc, js or php. The problem was with the Mac Server access permission on the PIE folder that I downloaded and unzipped. It was set to no access for user everyone. Changed access to readonly and now it works! Rookie mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

do not use this with css3pie:

```
 filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#', endColorstr='#')";
```

my problem solved