# PIE.htc Content-Type text/html

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to use the pie.htc file within a MVC 3 project using IIS 7. I've gone into the MIME settings for the server and .htc files are set to the correct text/x-component. Looking in the explorer development tools, it is still being served as text/html for some reason and so is throwing a 404. Has anyone run into this issue before? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Pie not working at All, tried everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853037/css3-pie-not-working-at-all-tried-everything)